# Live database fetch using Laravel and React

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, reactjs, laravel

I'm new to React and still learning Laravel, and I was wondering how can I live fetch data from the database using the Laravel Controllers. I want to use React too but I really don't see his utility there.

From my searches, I found an Ajax method, but I really want to use just Laravel and React to do so. Is it possible?

Like displaying the new users directly from the database without refreshing the whole page? I'm using Mysql to manage my database.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, You need to set up [laravel sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#introduction) to get the authenticated data.

But if you don't want the authenticated data. You can just use a fetching library like axios to fetch data from the laravel. You need to add the cors (which is localhost:3000) in app.cors.php file of laravel root directory.

But if you are using reacjs with laravel like with intertia.js (which I prefere btw), You don't need the cors, laravel will work out of the box....

Comment: Yes I did use axios as you mentionned. But fetching data was, i guess normal ? Like it wasn't live or anything, just a normal one. With intertia.js can I achieve the live realoading ?

Comment: yes, just watch some basic tutorial from youtube. InertiaJS actually provides really good support for reactjs

Comment: I guess there is a kind of hot realoading as I tested their demo app. But the problem is, I want to "push" new users to show in the dashboard. For example we have two accounts, one create a new user, the other account should see the new users pop-uping without refreshing anything. Any idea ?

Comment: In that case, you will probably need a WebSocket or laravel channel broadcasting..

Comment: Yes that what I thought, but it will tax the server I guess no ?